# C++ Correct way to Deference and Assign Value to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Let say I simply want a function that takes a pointer as a parameter, dereferences it, and then makes it equal to a newly instantiated class..

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(int v) {value = v;}

    int value;
}

Set_New_Class(MyClass *x) {
    *x = *( new MyClass(1) );       // Messy!!
}
```

What bothers me is the last line.. To me it seems messy and in fact, i'm not even sure if it is the right way to do it...

Is there anything wrong with my approach, and what's the correct way to do this in c++?

Comment: `MyClass &x` and `x = MyClass(1);`?

Comment: `Is there anything wrong with my approach?` Memory leak I guess

Comment: why don't you put a return type for your function Set_New_Class ? void would be right. By default C++ says it's int. However it's not good practive not define a return type, and not to return anything in a function

Comment: @StephaneRolland, C++ says no such thing. You're thinking of C.

Comment: No i'm thinking of good pratice. You write your return type for a function prototype: period. Whether in C++ or in C.

Answer (score 4):

There's really no use for a function like `Set_New_Class`.  Just create another constructor, which assigns 1 to `value` by default:

```
class MyClass 
{
    MyClass(int v) : value(v) {} 
    MyClass() : value(1) {}

    int value;
};
```

Then

```
MyClass x;
```

will give you what you want here I expect, in general.  Where `x` has been previously defined and you want to redefine it, then

```
x = MyClass();
```

will do it.

Comment: In absence of any justification for complication your solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your solution is that it creates an object dynamically with `new` and then copies from that object, leaving that object hanging around in the ether. That is, you have a memory leak.

Instead, you should just create a temporary object and assign that to the object you passed in:

```
void Set_New_Class(MyClass *x) {
    *x = MyClass(1);
}
```

However, [raw pointers are usually not the best choice](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/avoiding-ambiguity-raw-pointers.html), and in this case we can use a reference type instead:

```
void Set_New_Class(MyClass& x) {
    x = MyClass(1);
}
```

However, I'm find that output parameters like this are usually unnecessary, so I suggest that a better solution is to actually return the new object and assign it to `x` outside:

```
MyClass Get_New_Class() {
    return MyClass(1);
}

// Somewhere else:
x = Get_New_Class();
```

Of course, having a function at all is only necessary at all if you actually need to do something complex to create the new object. If not, just do this:

```
x = MyClass(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointers in C++ are passed by value. Therefore if you want to assign the pointer that way, you need to pass a pointer to that pointer:

```
void Set_New_Class(MyClass **x) {
    *x = new MyClass(1);
}
```

Otherwise outside of the function, it will still retain its old value.

A note that the comments have brought up, is that the replacing the previous value this way can result in a memory leak and this approach should be avoided all together.

Comment: Not only that, but they allocated a `new MyClass` that immediately falls out of scope and becomes unreachable, therefore leaking that new object every time.

Comment: Arguments to functions taking by reference aren't passed by value.

Comment: hmmm... and what happens to the memory that `x` points before `new`?

Comment: It leaks if OP doesn't take care of it.

Comment: Although your observation is correct and that is most important I would not propose such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports C++11 you could take advantage of smart pointers and especially `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyClass {
  int value;
public:
  MyClass(int v) {value = v;}
  int getvalue() const { return value; }
};

void Set_New_Class(std::unique_ptr<MyClass> &x) {
  x.reset(new MyClass(1)); // safe old memory is deleted
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<MyClass> x(new MyClass(2));
  std::cout << x->getvalue() << std::endl;
  Set_New_Class(x);
  std::cout << x->getvalue() << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ac501720d9b08a6)

This way you won't worry about deleting the memory allocated and memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You have have a major memory leak due to assigning via new:

```
*x = *( new MyClass(1) );
```

You can resolve it with

```
*x = MyClass(1);
```

However, it is still ugly passing a reference or pointer which will get a (return) value. Hence, leaving it to return value optimizations (copy elision) and/or constructors (r-value references) it becomes:

```
MyClass new_class() { return MyClass(1); }
```

Which is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

'new' already returns a pointer, so all you need to do is:

```
*x = new MyClass(1);
```

Comment: That won't compile, check the types.